# Why is a double primitive a BigDecimal in groovy

Tags: groovy

I call an overloaded method (assertThat) which has one signature with a BigDecimal parameter and another one with double primitive parameter.
When I launch this snippet in groovy, it calls the one with BigDecimal parameter when I was expecting the double primitive parameter one to be called.

```
double[] erreur = Seg.erreur(xtab, ytab, 0, 2)
Assertions.assertThat(erreur[1]).isEqualTo(-0.3333333333333333)
```

Can someone explain me why ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Assertions` junit?

Comment: No Assertions is AssertJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a decimal number in groovy is a `BigDecimal`. If you want it to be a double, you should use the suffix  `D` or `d`:

From [Number type suffixes](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#_number_type_suffixes) in the docs:

```
assert 123.45 == new BigDecimal('123.45') // default BigDecimal type used
assert 1.200065D == new Double('1.200065')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isEqualsTo()` is passing a BigDecimal as parameter, whereas your `assertThat()` is passing a double. Just add a `d` at the end of that `-0.3333333333333333` and it should work:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

class Doubles extends GroovyTestCase {

  void testAssertions() {
    double[] erreur = [0.1, -0.3333333333333333, 0.3]
    assertThat(erreur[1]).isEqualTo(-0.3333333333333333d)
  }

}
```